# getting a null pointer exception on fetching device id

Tags: android

While fetching device id in Samsung Galaxy Player 3.6 running Android GingerBread 2.3.6 app crashes. Line of code used:

```
((TelephonyManager) activity.getSystemService( Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE )).getDeviceId();
```

This line of code returns a null value. It doesn't work specifically with device mentioned above. We have tested on HTC One X, LG devices and Morola Droid as well as on Samsung Ace and Samsung S.

Comment: This code works fine with most of the devices which we have except for the one mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is, because the Galaxy Player is no phone. Therefore it has no `TELEPHONY_SERVICE`.

To get a unique identifier for each Android device, see this official blog post:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have provided permission READ_PHONE_STATE to the application in manifest file.

Comment: Yes i do have permission set in Manifest. This is happening specific for the device mentioned - Samsung Galaxy Player 3.6 running Android GingerBread 2.3.6